# How to escape characters in ProxyPassReverse directive?

Tags: apache, escaping, reverse-proxy

I am running an application at `http://localhost:5820/myDB#!/` which I would like to deploy through Apache2 using reverse proxy. But my application responds with

> "Database 'myDB%23!' does not exist."

How do I escape the *#* and  *!* characters? I could not find this in the Apache documentation. Backslash doesn't seem to work:

```
ProxyPass /sparql http://localhost:5820/myDB\#\!
ProxyPassReverse /sparql http://localhost:5820/myDB\#\!
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: `#` is a difficult character to use in this context because it has a special role in URLs, and hence *must* be URL encoded into `%23` if it's supposed to be used as part of the URL. The easiest solution would probably be not using it in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @ Pekka 웃 but unfortunately I cannot avoid using that URL. I have managed to escape the characters with a rewrite rule instead: `RewriteRule ^/myDB$ http://localhost:5820/myDB#!  [NE,P]` which works, but now my app returns: "Database 'myDB#!' does not exist." but when I type the same URL locally, `http://localhost:5820/myDB#!` it works, so now I'm really stuck.